# Array of Checkbox Value through AJAX to Laravel Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table of data where each row has a checkbox with the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="batchCheckbox" name="batch[]" value="(item id)">
```

I have an AJAX script which is called when I press a download button:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#downloadTableData').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/carrier/api/osd/download',
        data: {'batch[]': $('.batchCheckbox:checked').serialize(),
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
              },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('Data downloaded.');
        }
    });
  });
 });
</script>
```

Now, as it stands this is what is sent via the request:

```
batch[]: batch%5B%5D=83&batch%5B%5D=66
_token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxGSSMWc
```

When in reality, it should be sending an array of values for batch: 83, 66

In my controller, I return a dd of $request->batch just to verify and this is what is returned:

```
array:1 [
  0 => "batch[]=83&batch[]=66"
]
```

Obviously, I require the numbers alone, is there a better way of formatting my AJAX to better request the batch[] data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should use serializeArray and get value

```
<script>
function getValueCheckbox() {
    $('.batchCheckbox:checked').serializeArray().map(function (obj) {
       return obj.value
    })
}
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#downloadTableData').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/carrier/api/osd/download',
        data: {
               'batch[]': getValueCheckbox(),
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
              },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('Data downloaded.');
        }
    });
  });
 });
</script>
```